# Django plural translation of days and hours not working

Tags: python, django, localization, translation

Here's my function, which I use to display delays. Delays can be positive (if there's delay) or negative. This function takes timedelta as argument.

```
def delta_string(delta):
        days = delta.days
        hours = delta.seconds/3600
        if days < 0 and hours > 0: 
            days = days + 1
            hours = 24 - hours
        days_string = ungettext("%(day)s day","%(day)s days", abs(days)) % {'day': days}
        hours_string = ungettext("%(hour)s hour","%(hour)s hours", hours) % {'hour': hours}
        return "%s, %s" % (days_string, hours_string)
```

Of course, all string are translated in po file (and compiled). However, the results are strange - sometimes the translation is correct, sometimes not. Examples:

> 35 days, 9 hours; -4 dni, 1 godzina; 0 days, 11 hours; 19 days, 13
>   hours; 34 dni, 9 hours; -1 dzień, 6 hours; -1 dzień, 2 godzin; -5
>   days, 4 godzin; 3 dni, 19 hours

and so on. Whole of the output above is displayed on the same page. What might be wrong? I tried ungettext_lazy as well, tried u"string" - no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rolling out your own solution, use Django's built-in [`timesince` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince) (if you need this functionality within a template) or `timesince` function in `django.utils.timesince`. These will handle translation for you.

Comment: Nice, thanks! It's a pitty it doesn't work in both directions (ie. if first argument is later date than second, give negative result).

Comment: For the other direction, you can use the `timeuntil` filter [ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil ]

Comment: Yes, I know, but than I have to check if my first date is later than second one.